# couldn't find local name "" in the initial cluster configuration when start etcd service

Tags: etcd

I am start etcd(v3.3.15) service using this command:

```
systemctl start etcd
```

this is my etcd systemd config:

```
[Unit]
Description=Etcd Server
After=network.target
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target
Documentation=https://github.com/coreos

[Service]
Type=notify
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/etcd/
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/etcd/etcd.conf
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/etcd \
  --name ${ETCD_NAME} \
  --cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kubernetes.pem \
  --key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kubernetes-key.pem \
  --peer-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kubernetes.pem \
  --peer-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/kubernetes-key.pem \
  --trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem \
  --peer-trusted-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem \
  --initial-advertise-peer-urls ${ETCD_INITIAL_ADVERTISE_PEER_URLS} \
  --listen-peer-urls ${ETCD_LISTEN_PEER_URLS} \
  --listen-client-urls ${ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS},http://127.0.0.1:2379 \
  --advertise-client-urls ${ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS} \
  --initial-cluster-token ${ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_TOKEN} \
  --initial-cluster infra1=https://172.19.104.231:2380,infra2=https://172.19.104.230:2380,infra3=https://172.19.150.82:2380 \
  --initial-cluster-state new \
  --data-dir=${ETCD_DATA_DIR}
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
LimitNOFILE=65536

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and this is my etcd config:

```
# [member]
ETCD_NAME=infra1
ETCD_DATA_DIR="/var/lib/etcd"
ETCD_LISTEN_PEER_URLS="https://172.19.150.82:2380"
ETCD_LISTEN_CLIENT_URLS="https://172.19.150.82:2379"

#[cluster]
ETCD_INITIAL_ADVERTISE_PEER_URLS="https://172.19.150.82:2380"
ETCD_INITIAL_CLUSTER_TOKEN="etcd-cluster"
ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS="https://172.19.150.82:2379"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your IPs or names mismatch.

> **infra3**=https://172.19.150.82

and

```
ETCD_NAME=infra1
ETCD_DATA_DIR="/var/lib/etcd"
ETCD_LISTEN_PEER_URLS="https://172.19.150.82:2380"
```

Comment: This post saved my day. My ETCD_NAME value and  --initial-cluster  values had a mismatch. :) Thanks a lot,